# matplotlib on anaconda on mac os x

Tags: matplotlib, anaconda, macos-high-sierra

Anaconda has documented issue with matplotlib on mac os x. I am newbie, please provide color by numbers if possible.

I have seen recommended fixes and tried to apply with no success.

1. conda install python.app - i am told environment exists, no changes are made
2. "replace the use of python with pythonw" - i have no idea where to make that change.
3. include import matplotlib as mpl  mpl.use('TkAgg') causes the kernel in spyder to crash

Can anyone please provide more detail or other options?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what is being asked for here. I suggest clarifying the question.

Comment: you could try to just install matplotlib with pip, so: pip install matplotlib

Comment: The question to community is: do you have other recommendations on how to trouble shoot this issue?  The three most common options (provided above) have not worked.  I will try to re-install matplotlib. Thanks.

Comment: I found the fix. Under spyder preferences, python interpreter, insert /anaconda3/bin/pythonw for a default installation.